# SELECT cell value and apply for all rows based on ID

Tags: sql

How can I take value from cell and display for all rows that belongs to current id?

Example of table:

| id | event | parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111 | session_start | value_1 |
| 1111111 | page_view | null |
| 1111111 | page_view | null |
| 2222222 | session_start | value_2 |
| 2222222 | page_view | null |
| 2222222 | page_view | null |
| 3333333 | session_start | value_3 |
| 3333333 | page_view | null |
| 3333333 | page_view | null |

Output:

| id | event | parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111 | session_start | value_1 |
| 1111111 | page_view | value_1 |
| 1111111 | page_view | value_1 |
| 2222222 | session_start | value_2 |
| 2222222 | page_view | value_2 |
| 2222222 | page_view | value_2 |
| 3333333 | session_start | value_3 |
| 3333333 | page_view | value_3 |
| 3333333 | page_view | value_3 |

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a CTE or subquery here (both are far too complicated for this use case) and I also don't think using an aggregate function like `MIN` is correct here. This would also replace other values if present, not only `NULL` values.

In my opinion, this is a perfect use case for `FIRST_VALUE` with `COALESCE`.

You didn't tag your DBMS, but most today's DBMS will correctly execute following query:

```
SELECT id, event, 
COALESCE(parameter, FIRST_VALUE(parameter) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id)) AS parameter
FROM mytable;
```

This will get the first value for each id. And this value will be set only in case the original value is `NULL`, otherwise the value will not be changed.

Try out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b47fe1/1)